# Laravel Eloquent relationship data hidden in response

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two models: `User` and `Group`. A `user` can be a member of just one `group`, and a `group` can have multiple `users`:

**User:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $visible = ['user_id', 'name', 'points', 'group_id', 'profile'];


    /**
     * Get group where user belongs to
     */
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Group', 'group_id', 'group_id');
    }
}
```

**Group:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Group extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'group';
    protected $primaryKey = 'group_id';

    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $visible = ['group_id', 'name', 'profile'];

    /**
     * Get all group users.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User', 'group_id', 'group_id');
    }
}
```

Now in my controller, I want to retrieve the user data and the users' group data. Therefore I use this:

```
$users = User::with('group')
        ->orderBy('points', 'DESC')
        ->take(50)
        ->get();

return response()->json($users);
```

So far so good. I expect the above to return something like this:

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 27,
    "name": "linnie15",
    "points": 18565,
    "group_id": 6,
    "profile": null,
    "group": {
      "group_id": 6,
      "name": "White Wall",
      "profile": "Et tempore voluptatibus sunt ratione ut. Eum sint mollitia omnis eius ut facilis aut. Sed quisquam quis velit qui sint soluta. Autem quia ipsam esse sapiente delectus vel."
    }
  },
]
```

But, here is the problem. The only thing it returns is this:

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 27,
    "name": "linnie15",
    "points": 18565,
    "group_id": 6,
    "profile": null
  },
]
```

How is that possible? In fact, I found the solution, by adding `'group'` to the `$visible` array in the `User` model. But why is that? I mean, should I really add all my relationships to the `$visible` array? Why would that be necessary. If you query a relationship, you always want the result, isn't it?

Comment: The `$visible` property explicitly whitelists what data can be shown. Anything not in that will not be shown. If you wanted everything to be shown by default (including relatinships) and only hide certain things you should have a `$hidden` property defined instead.

Comment: Iff you want to go deeper in the control of your JSON responses take a look at fractals (https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal)

Answer (score 0):

As by seeing your code, the relationship between user and group would be supposed to be like this (you shouldn't give the 3rd argument in hasMany() relationsip):

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Group', 'group_id');
```

Same case for method `users()` in Group model:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Model\User');
```

According to [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), the `hasMany()` takes:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Model', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

> Remember that you must add all the properties in `$visible`
>
> [See visibility docs from Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't really matter for the output. Still the same: the group data is not visible in the json output..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your case you must add all your properties in the `visible` array. If you don't want to do that, use `$hidden` instead of `$visible`, and put inside it only the properties that you don't want to be visible in your responses.

The same happens with `$fillable` and `$guarded`, you must use just one of them.

---

**EXTRA**:

I would like to add that it's not necessary to do `return response()->json($users);`. In Laravel 5.3 you can just `return $users;` and will be automatically returned as a json array.

Answer (score 0):

Well sir you have a problem in relations defined. The third parameter should be `user_id`. Try following code and let me know

```
/** * Get group where user belongs to  */ 
public function group() { 
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Group', 'group_id', 'user_id'); 
 }
```